# Append same string to all variables in column of CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, for-loop, replace, each

I would like help on how to add string `-Config` to each name in column Name.

CSV file contains:

```
FullName             Name    LastWriteTime
\\remotecomputer\    Henry   4/30/2020  3:44:57 PM
\\remotecompter\     Magy    12/7/2020  9:04:28 PM
```

The desired output:

```
FullName             Name    LastWriteTime
\\remotecomputer\    Henry-Config   4/30/2020  3:44:57 PM
\\remotecompter\     Magy-Config    12/7/2020  9:04:28 PM
```

My current code:

```
$InvoiceList = Import-CSV -Path C:\$source-PREP.csv | foreach($list in $InvoiceList){
$Name=$($list.name)
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Names' -Filter *.txt | where {$_.Name -like '*' }|Copy-Item -Destination 'c:\newfolder' -Force }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your file has only a few known columns, you could use `Select-Object` and append `-Config` to the values in the Name column using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1#select-object):

```
$data = Import-CSV -Path "C:\$source-PREP.csv" | 
        Select-Object FullName, @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {'{0}-Config' -f $_.Name}}, LastWriteTime
$data | Export-Csv -Path "C:\$source-PREP.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Result

```
FullName          Name         LastWriteTime    
--------          ----         -------------    
\\remotecomputer\ Henry-Config 4/30/2020 3:44:57
\\remotecompter\  Magy-Config  12/7/2020 9:04:28
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate of each line in the CSV and update the name property. Once done export back out to CSV

```
$csvfile = 'some\path\to\file.csv'

$csvdata = Import-Csv $csvfile

$csvdata | ForEach-Object {$_.name = $_.name + '-Config'}

$csvdata | Export-Csv $csvfile -NoTypeInformation
```